# Imitate post request triggered by button on website in python requests

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, post, python-requests

I'm attempting to imitate the post request being triggered by the 'Download as CSV' button the webpage https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/pub/en/nlp?2. However I'm consistently returning an error webpage rather than the csv file.

Inspecting the html for the button gives the following:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/pub/en/nlp?2-2.-top~csv~form~panel-form" id="idf2"><div id="idf2_hf_0" hidden="" class="hidden-fields"></div>

<a class="btn btn-green argus-A98" target="_blank" href="https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/pub/en/nlp?2--top~csv~form~panel-form-csv~resource~link" title="Download as CSV"><span>Download as CSV</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-file-csv"></i></a>
</form>
```

I had interpreted this as the html request being sent to the 'action' url with the payload id='idf2', and wrote the following snipet:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/pub/en/nlp?2--top~csv~form~panel-form-csv~resource~link'
payload = {'id': 'idf2'}

r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
r.content
```

However this just returns a webpage saying that there's been an error. Is there something I'm missing from my request? I also tried supplying a 'User-Agent' in the headers, but this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Whats the status code? `r.status_code`

Comment: >>> r.status_code
200

Comment: Try doing a `.get()` on that url, not a `.post()`, with no payload.  I don't believe the form action is actually being called at all, because the thing you click on is a plain `<a>` link, not a form submit button.

Comment: Just running `.get()` seems to return the same error page unfortunately, although Andrej's answer seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to first open the main page and then add `--top~csv~form~panel-form-csv~resource~link` to the URL:

```py
import requests


url = "https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/pub/en/nlp?0--top~csv~form~panel-form-csv~resource~link"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0",
    "Referer": "https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/",
}

with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    s.get("https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/pub/en/nlp?0")

    with open("out.csv", "wb") as f_out:
        f_out.write(s.get(url).content)
```

Creates `out.csv`:

```
"Positionsinhaber","Emittent","ISIN","Position","Datum"
"Qube Research & Technologies Limited","Rheinmetall Aktiengesellschaft","DE0007030009","0,68","2023-10-19"
"Caius Capital LLP","Deutsche Pfandbriefbank AG","DE0008019001","2,92","2023-10-19"
"Millennium International Management LP","Deutsche Pfandbriefbank AG","DE0008019001","0,69","2023-10-19"
"Marshall Wace LLP","TAG Immobilien AG","DE0008303504","0,50","2023-10-19"
"SIH Partners, LLLP","Northern Data AG","DE000A0SMU87","1,06","2023-10-19"
"Qube Research & Technologies Limited","VARTA AKTIENGESELLSCHAFT","DE000A0TGJ55","0,58","2023-10-19"
"Marshall Wace LLP","adidas AG","DE000A1EWWW0","0,69","2023-10-19"
"Marble Bar Asset Management LLP","SÜSS MicroTec SE","DE000A1K0235","1,17","2023-10-19"
"Qube Research & Technologies Limited","flatexDEGIRO AG","DE000FTG1111","0,82","2023-10-19"

...
```

Comment: This works! Thanks for the help. Out of interest - what is running `get` on the main page first doing? Why is this step necessary?

Comment: @LukeBradley It gets the session cookie that is used in subsequent requests.